# Azure CosmosDb CreateTransactionalBatch with FeedIterator or conditional statement

Tags: transactions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos Version="3.23.0" in .net Core project.
I am using transaction library for the operations. I want to create a transaction where an Item should be deleted, if the count of documents using a particular property is 0. All the documents are within the same container and using same partition Key.
e.g. There are documents for people with property

```
Id: 
PartitionKey: ffff
Name:
LastName: 
Occupation:
```

There is second document for occupation:

```
Id:
ParitionKey: ffff
Occupation:
Salary:
```

I want to delete occupation document if there are no people documents using this occupation.
I can write query to get count of documents where Occupation is of specific value and then want to delete if count is 0. Wondering if I can do all this using transaction library.

I would write the query to get count something like this -

```
QueryDefinition queryDefinition =
            new QueryDefinition("SELECT value count(1) FROM c WHERE (c.occupationId= @occupationId)")
                 .WithParameter("@occupationId", occupationId.ToString()));

                    using (FeedIterator<long> feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<long>(
                        queryDefinition: queryDefinition,
                        requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
                        {
                            PartitionKey = partitionKey
                        }))
                    {
                        while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
                        {
                            FeedResponse<long> response = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync(cancellationToken);
                            
                            long tempCount = response.Sum();
                            docuCount+= tempCount;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: You can include multiple operations using Transactional Batch in Cosmos DB SDK (inserts, updates, deletes) which will all execute within a transaction but it is not possible to enlist a query in a transaction.  The only thing that provides some amount of conditional execution is Partial Document Updates but you cannot use those to delete a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TransactionalBatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/transactional-batch) can only contain point operations (Read, Create, Replace, Delete, Patch), no queries.

And cannot contain conditions (for example, one of the operations depending on the result of a previous one).