# How can I delete all documents by one partition in one collection in Cosmos db by one query(or in the best way)?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Can I delete all documents by one partition in one collection in Cosmos db by one query?

In my cosmos db database I have more then 100 thousand notifications because of bug in my code. Now I fix bug and need delete this notifications. I try to find solution how to delete this in the best way. Could you help me?

Comment: This has already been addressed in other questions here, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698074/azure-cosmosdb-createtransactionalbatch-with-feediterator-or-conditional-stateme). Tl;dr there is no way to just "drop" or "delete" all data associated with a single partition key. Yes, you can batch-delete some data within a partition, within an atomic transaction, but there are time and count limits.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write code or use a third party tool like Cerebrata which can delete all documents based on a query.

Disclaimer: I do not work for Cerebrata nor do I get paid for recommending them I am simply a happy user of their product.